# Reading from STDIN from command line redirection only

Tags: c, command-line

My goal is to have a program that can take user input from a file redirection in C.

```
$ ./hello < input.txt
```

But when there is no redirection or arguments the program will output a message :

```
$ ./hello
There is nothing to read!
```

Since file redirection goes directly into stdin, I'm using scanf to read the contents of the file. However when I start the program without a redirection `scanf` waits for input and my goal is to get it ONLY from the redirection on the command line if there's nothing it outputs the message

Comment: What do you want to do about `cat input.txt | ./hello`?  You can look to see if standard input is a terminal — `isatty()` in POSIX.  But that won't help with piped data.  Identifying a pipe as the input is non-trivial.  It would be trivial, and would save the users some typing, if you specified `./hello input.txt` and objected if there was no argument to read.  You should also decide what to do if there are multiple names specified — don't just ignore the extra ones; either process them or complain about their presence.

Comment: Why do you require this behavior that's somewhat unusual for a standard command line application?

Comment: Stop thinking "goes to".  When you run your program via `./hello < input.txt`, the file `input.txt` doesn't "go to" stdin.  It *is* stdin.  You can fseek, and rewind, and do whatever you like.   Perhaps you just want to use `isatty`, or perhaps you could try to seek and see if `stdin` is seekable, or perhaps you want something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to non-portably checking if stdin is a tty or not, the shell cannot tell where the input is coming from, it can only tell if it is already there or not.  You don't say what platform you're on, and I am assuming what you really want is just /for the read to not block/ - you can achieve this by polling `stdin` in a non-blocking fashion:

```
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int poll_stdin() {
struct timeval tv;
fd_set fds;

    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds); 
    select(STDIN_FILENO+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    return FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);
}

size_t read_stdin(char *buf, size_t max) {
size_t n = 0;

   while ((n < max) && (poll_stdin())) {
      read(STDIN_FILENO, &buf[n++], 1);
   }
   if (n < max-1) buf[n] = '\0';
   return n;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char buf[255];
size_t len;

   buf[255] = '\0';
   len = read_stdin(buf, 255);
   if (len == 0) printf("No input!\n");
   else printf(">%s\n", buf);
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
dtrombley@squall:~$ echo 'Hello, world!' > hello.txt
dtrombley@squall:~$ ./main
No input!
dtrombley@squall:~$ ./main < hello.txt
>Hello, world!
```

Comment: This may work "weirdly" with pipes, tho - you can probably catch it receiving only part of the input under some circumstances....

Comment: To get around this, you could also do a version that polls just once and then does a scanf.   But you should be aware that CLI users will be very very annoyed at you trying to second-guess them in either case.   Everyone expects your command line utility to block for the user to get input.   That is the Way of CLI.  If you make it not do that, you will break someone's script, somehow, somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

### Use isatty()

That is exactly what it is for.

Be aware that not all systems provide a sane isatty(), but any *nixen that claims POSIX compliance will work properly. Here is my current go-to code for *nixen (adapted to C):

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>

bool my_isatty( int id )
{
  return (0 <= id) and (id <= 2) and isatty( id );
}
```

There are all kinds of wrinkles on Windows, particularly if you are using the MSYS2 shell (which implements the command window using pipes, LOL, so you have to play with some low-level OS stuff to check that).